# Редактирование пакетов TCP/IP

Tags: tcp-ip, reverse-engineering

Для тестирования мне необходимо изменить параметр `src` в определённых пакетах, в слое IP, подставив туда например мусор. Scapy не даёт сделать данную процедуру. Возможен ли данный вектор атаки и какими программами возможно отредактировать данный параметр?

Comment: В теории, вроде, Wireshark (вплоть до, собственно, WinPcap) имеет исходник - почему бы этим не воспользоваться, чтобы создать на его основе именно утилиту для модификации? Но на практике я бы просто зашел с другой стороны - изменения в приложении клиента или сервера (смотря какое доступно).

Comment: Можно применить dll-hijacking с подставной `ws2_32.dll`. Хотя готовую обертку, которая называлась Generica, нынче днем с огнем не сыщешь.

Comment: Чтобы было понятнее, интересующий меня параметр принимается и сохраняется на сервере в стек, чуть выше адреса возврата. Задача затереть его.

Comment: Кстати, а разве этот параметр не фиксированный размер имеет? на IP 4 байта выделяется. Я сомневаюсь, что вы там что-то затереть сможете.